# How to find the index of an item in a list, but not an exact match

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, indexing

I have a list something like this:

```py
ls = ['item1', 'this is item2', 'item3']
```

I want to be able to find the index of the item `'this is item2'` by searching for `'item2'`. The index function is looking for the exact match so it wouldn't help here:

```py
index = ls.index('item2')
```

How can I achieve this requirement?

Comment: Have you done any research? Have you tried anything?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a solution using `next` with a generator, and `enumerate` to get the index:

```py
>>> ls = ['item1', 'this is item2', 'item3']
>>> next(i for i, v in enumerate(ls) if 'item2' in v)
1
```

It will raise `StopIteration` if the item is not found. If you want `None` or `-1` instead, you can give it as the second argument to `next`:

```py
>>> next((i for i, v in enumerate(ls) if 'item5' in v), -1)
-1
```

Answer (score 1):

You may simply pass by a temporary list and apply index method on it:

```
ls = ['item1', 'this is item2', 'item3']
index = ['item2' in item for item in ls].index(True)
```